# What is the appropriate translation for "stick" (one that falls off a tree)?

Tags: translation, word-choice

Usually when you look up the word "stick", you get something like

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%A3%8D%E6%A3%92) 棍棒 (gùn​bàng​) club / staff / stick

Google Image Search indicates a 棍棒 looks like this:

> [image: a short wooden rod, looks similar to a rolling pin]

and not like this:

> [image: a stick, one that could have recently come off a tree]

In English, if someone says the word "stick" (as a noun), they're usually envisaging this latter image.  I'm struggling to find an appropriate translation for "stick".

**Question**: What is the appropriate translation for "stick" (one that falls off a tree)?

Comment: Do you mean *tree branch* (樹枝)?

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not sure.  In English a "branch" is larger than a "stick", and a stick tends to be 1-dimensional, whereas a branch would usually branch off into 2+ dimensions.  Children tend to play with sticks (e.g. to dig holes), but branches are too big.  We might throw a stick and tell our dog to fetch it.

Comment: Quote:- " In English a "branch" is larger than a "stick"" I am interested to know the etymological sources for this classification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

树枝，枝条，枝子

I didn't know in English a "branch" is larger than a "stick". Thanks for telling us that. In Chinese we usually don't make such distinctions. If you want to emphasize it is small, just add 小 before it, eg. 小树枝，小枝条，小枝子.

Answer (score 2):

simply, it's different.

**樹枝**、**枝條** is that thing in the tree. Like braches or sticks
**棍棒**、**棍子** is a thing can hit people. Man-made.

Answer (score 0):

'sticks' don't fall off trees (maybe in America?), branches, small branches or twigs fall of trees.

树枝， 小树枝， 枝桠

twig is definitely related to the Sanskrit root for two.